# What is the SoftLayer API to order a new message queue and access its credentials?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I need to order a new softlayer message queue account programmatically. This is the same function that is performed in the control.softlayer.com portal under Services->Messages->"Order Message Queue".

Can anyone point me at the API for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the following Rest example:

```
 https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Order/verifyOrder
```

Note: Change from `verifyOrder` to `placeOrder` when order is ready.

```
 Method: POST

 {
  "parameters": [
    {
      "location": "DALLAS05",
      "packageId": 212,
      "prices": [
        {
          "id": 20826
        }
      ],
      "quantity": 1,
      "complexType": "SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Network_Message_Queue"
    }
  ]
}
```

To get valid prices for package 212, please execute:

```
 https://[username]:[apikey]@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Product_Package/212/getItemPrices?objectMask=mask[id,item[keyName,description],pricingLocationGroup[locations[id, name, longName]]]
 Method: GET
```

**Some References:**

http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getItemPrices http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package/getAllObjects 
http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Product_Package 
http://sldn.softlayer.com/blog/cmporter/Location-based-Pricing-and-You
https://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/procedure/access-message-queue-account-credentials
https://sldn.softlayer.com/article/message-queue-getting-started